# How to send Ms Azure push notifications to android device from Postman

Tags: android, firebase, azure, postman, android-push-notification

I am trying to send Azure push notification to android devices by using Postman. To achieve this i saw post in [microsoftDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/direct-send) but docs saying that **This API doesn't support Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) yet.** Is there any way to send FCM push notification from postman by using MsAzure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution

**URL**

```
https://{namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{NotificationHub}/messages/?api-version=2015-01
```

**Parameter**

- Headers

  ```
  Authorization                   {{azure-authorization}}
  Content-Type                    application/json
  ServiceBusNotification-Format   gcm
  ```
- Body (Body will be according to you. No need to maintain as below)

  ```
  {"data":{"gcm.notification.body":"Hi", "gcm.notification.title":"Hi"}}
  ```
- Pre-request Script

  ```
  function getAuthHeader(resourceUri, keyName, key) {

      var d = new Date();
      var sinceEpoch = Math.round(d.getTime() / 1000);
      var expiry = (sinceEpoch + 3600);
      var stringToSign = encodeURIComponent(resourceUri) + '\n' + expiry;
      var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, key);
      var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
      var sasToken = 'SharedAccessSignature sr=' + encodeURIComponent(resourceUri) + '&sig=' + encodeURIComponent(hashInBase64) + '&se=' + expiry + '&skn=' + keyName;
      console.log(sasToken);
      alert(sasToken);

      return sasToken;
  }
  postman.setEnvironmentVariable('azure-authorization', getAuthHeader(request.url,"DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
  postman.setEnvironmentVariable('current-date',new Date().toUTCString());
  ```

In the above code (Pre-request Script) we have to update DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature for that follow the below steps

Go to Azure portal | Access Policies | Copy the DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature and paste some where | from there copy the SharedAccessKey

**Images for reference**

*Pic 1:*
[image]

*Pic 2:*
[image]

*Pic 3:*
[image]